# Django 'distinct' returning multiple values

Tags: python, django, distinct

I know this subject was discussed here, but I really can't get this to work... :(
I have this DeviceLocation model:

```
class DeviceLocation(models.Model):
        device = models.ForeignKey(Device, related_name='locations', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
        device_imei = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='device_locations', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
        user_username = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
        timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
        latitude = models.FloatField()
        longitude = models.FloatField()
        accuracy = models.FloatField()
        speed = models.FloatField()
```

I want to get the last location for each different device, in the last 5 min. So I tried this:

```
time_now = datetime.now()
time_from = time_now.replace(minute=time_now.minute - 5)
last_device_locations = DeviceLocation.objects.filter(timestamp__range=(time_from, time_now)).distinct('device')
```

The thing is, distinct is not working... Return multiple results for the same device. 
I searched the site and found a work-around using values, even so I can't do it:

> > > DeviceLocation.objects.filter(timestamp__range=(time_from, time_now)).values('device', 'timestamp').order_by('device').distinct('device')

but this still doesn't work... :(
Any hints?

Thank you!

Comment: According to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) passing field names to `distinct()` is only supported in PostgreSQL. Are you using PostgreSQL?

Comment: What's more, it's a Django 1.4 feature. Are you running trunk or the alpha?

Comment: @isbadawi i'm running PGSQL...

Comment: @Alasdair I'm running trunk... Sorry, my mistake :(. Anyways, do you guys have any hint on how I can get that to work? It doens't forcefully has to use distinct().

Comment: The thing is I want to return the whole object, not just some values

Comment: i've the almost the same issue. Mysql gave me a resultset and distinct was not enough. i use list(set(mylist)) to delete duplicates.

Comment: You aren't using any field ordering (order_by) are you? If you do, these fields are included in the distinct field list by default and my produce unexpected results: http://readthedocs.org/docs/django/en/latest/ref/models/querysets.html#order-by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
DeviceLocation.objects.filter(timestamp__range=(time_from, time_now)).order_by('device', '-timestamp').distinct('device')
```

I'm not sure, but it may be that the .values() call is interacting with the select distinct.

Also, you want to add `'-timestamp'` to the .order_by() call, to make sure that you get the most recent location for each device.

Comment: Hi Ian,thank you but it didn't worked :(.
It still returns multiple results. But I think it has to do with the distinct() parameter, since I'm running 1.3.1 and it this only works in 1.4, I think.

I think I'll try a workaround, but I'd like to do it database side, without having to filter my results in my view.

TY,

Comment: Can you post the SQL query that is actually being executed? This is a new feature, and you may have found a bug.